# Restrict what customers an employee can see (NetSuite)

Tags: netsuite

I'm customizing some NetSuite objects (forms, etc) including the Employee Centre's Time Tracking form.  We want the people recording time (external contractors) to be able to enter time only against the projects and project tasks they have been explicitly assigned to.

So far it's going well, the only major problem is how to restrict what Customers they can see.

Currently the `Customer` field is where the system expects them to enter the name of the project, however that field will try to be "helpful" by listing/searching across the names of our customers as well.  I'm using a customized version of the OOTB Time Tracking form.

How can I restrict the system so that the user can only see the projects they have been assigned?  Or in other words, not see the entire customer base.

It's ok if they can also see the customer to whom the project belongs, and I'm open to solutions that are based on user access in the back-end (member for a group/role whatever, or, changing the way the Customer field works on the custom Time Tracking form.

Comment: Is that a custom field or standard ?

Comment: All key fields involved are standard