# How can I trigger a NetSuite workflow on a Form Event (Client side event)

Tags: netsuite

I want to trigger a NetSuite workflow when the user sets the value of a field, but I don't want to have them submit first.  The Workflow state builder looks like it has useful options but I can't get it to work.

There's some useful looking blog posts around but a lot of them seem out of date.

**Update - more info**

My primary issue is this one: [Restrict what customers an employee can see (NetSuite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825105/restrict-what-customers-an-employee-can-see-netsuite)

The hack I'm currently looking at is populating a custom Transaction Column Field that I've added to a custom Time Recording form.  The idea is to load this field on the UI with only valid projects (not customers as well), and this I have been able to do.

The problem is I still (as far as I can tell) still need to populate the "Customer" field, which is mandatory; I'm also assuming that if I don't do that then any time that is recorded won't go against the project. I had thought that if the user selects the project they want then I can populate the customer field with that value.  I hate this as an approach but I can't see how else to do it.  I do have coding experience (including JavaScript) but haven't made the leap into SuiteScript yet.

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you want? Usually you want a record to change state within a workflow, though it seems like you might just want a few fields to get set dependent on some others.

Comment: How about using `nlapiInitiateWorkflow` on a client script (field change)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a Workflow, as they are currently limited to only work with body level fields and cannot modify Transaction Column Fields (aka sublists).

You should be able to achieve this with a Client Side Script though.

[Source](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_N3915784.html) (Netsuite login required).

Sublist changes will be available for transactions in the 2018.1 release sometime in Feb/Mar.